# update-database - column does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I tried to use `update-database -verbose -force`, I get an error:

`ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'countReferralsRegistrations' does not exist in table 'UserProfile'.`

The problem is - I don't have (and I don't want to have) this column in model and also in table UserProfile.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION

use first: `Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges` and then
`update-database verbose`. This will work

Answer (score 0):

This will happen, because you may delete your Table column's manually and will update the database,

**This is the solution for this**.
  - Open the migration file which you created at last.
  - comment below lines and update-database again
  - DropForeignKey, DropIndex, DropColumn

Thank You..