# ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'xxx' does not exist in table 'yyy'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I make a mistake. I delete some row in table `__MigrationHistory` in my database.
and now when I run my project I force this error:

> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'xxx' does not exist in table 'yyy'.

How can I solved this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, finally I solved my problem.
I added field 'xxx' to table 'yyy' manually in my database.

Answer (score 11):

Add a new migration to re-synchronize:

```
add-migration MissingXXX -IgnoreChanges // tells EF to just take a snapshot
update-database
```

Now you are back in sync and can continue with future model changes.

Comment: Before, I try this solution in this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/15658406/1883345 but my problem wasn't solved

Comment: Did you get an error? Depending on where you are in development, you could just reset migrations by deleting __MigrationHistory and removing the Migration folder. Then add the initial migration from my answer. Another possibility is just deleting the migrations since the failed one before adding the new one.

Comment: Where do you enter this in?

Comment: Package Manager Console is one way. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: Solved My Problem! Thank you!

Comment: This just creates an empty migration file. Any idea why this is necessary? Thanks.

Comment: @CiaranGallagher Ciaran, correct - no Up() or Down() code is generated, but another key part of a migration is the snapshot. This is an xml representation of your current model (the classes that make up your entities). It is this code that is compared to your NEXT migration so only the differences are generated. See [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood).

Answer (score 1):

**Here is more details** since I had the same issue and this Question was help full:
For whatever reason if you get this error:
**ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN failed because column 'xxx' does not exist in table 'yyy'.** 
Do this: 
**manually update the table in the database**.

1. Go to Server Explorer (2)
2. Tables
3. Double click 'yyy'
4. Add:
   new column of 'xxx'
5. In the top left of Visual S under "Any CPU" there
   is an option "UPDATE".  This will update the table.
6. Now go to that table model under Models 'yyy.cs'
   Add: 
   public string 'xxx' {get; set;}
7. Now in PM ( tools --> Neu get package manger --> PM)
8. Do either update-migration or rollback it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not altering your table to recreat the missing column ? And then try to drop your table again :)

Answer (score 0):

I got this one using EF Core 3.1.1 while I was trying to add a new field to a table.

I didn't delete entries in the MigrationHistory table but I reverted the last migration, removed the generated migration files and generated them again with 'add migration'. Then I noticed the new Up and Down methods of the migrations where using AlterColumn instead of AddColumn and RemoveColumn. I got the code from the previous Up and Down methods and that solved it.